# IF returns false but should return true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

HTML:

```
    <div class="container" id="1" onclick="test()">  </div>
    <div class="container" id="2" onclick="test()">  </div>
    <div class="container" id="3" onclick="test()">  </div>
    <div class="container" id="4" onclick="test()">  </div>
```

JS:

```
{
        document.getElementById(e.target.id).appendChild(document.NewDiv("div", {id:"element1"}));

        if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("element1")) &&
            document.getElementById("2").contains(document.getElementById("element1")))
        {
            console.log("yes")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no")
        }
    };
```

This code returns "no" when element1 is in containers with id 1 and 2 but in my meaning it should be "yes"

But this code returns "yes" as should it be - if element1 is present in at least one of the two containers

```
    {
        document.getElementById(e.target.id).appendChild(document.NewDiv("div", {id:"element1"}));

        if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("element1")) || //<-- changed
            document.getElementById("2").contains(document.getElementById("element1")))
        {
            console.log("yes")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no")
        }
    };
```

I want this code to return "yes" if element1 is in container 1 and 2

```
    {
        document.getElementById(e.target.id).appendChild(document.NewDiv("div", {id:"element1"}));

        if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("element1")) &&
            document.getElementById("2").contains(document.getElementById("element1")))
        {
            console.log("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Include the HTML needed to reproduce the problem. Don't include code that isn't needed (e.g. the `test()` function wrapper and the `click` event handler) to reproduce the problem. Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same element in two different containers. Therefore the `&&` condition can't be true, while `||` can.

`id` attribute must be unique, you should not have more than one element with the same `id` in the same document.
If you happened to have multiple elements with the same `id`, only the first element can be selected with `document.getElementById()`.

However, theoretically you could use `myelement.querySelector('[id="element1"]')` to get element with `id` in the `myelement` container, but you should fix the code by not using the same ids.

```
        if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("1").querySelector("[id='element1']")) &&
            document.getElementById("2").contains(document.getElementById("2").querySelector("[id='element1']"))))
        {
            console.log("yes")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no")
        }
```